# Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Tags: python, django

I write a message board,When user leave message and success back to the page
I want to alert('sucess leaving message,Thank you very much.')
I found a method is to use `return redirect(reverse(...))`

But there is an error when I try :
`Reverse for '/maininfo/#5thPage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Please help me ,Thank you .

views.py

```
def maininfo(request):
    return render(request, 'zh_tw/maininfo.html',)

def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/maininfo/#5thPage')
            return redirect(reverse("/maininfo/#5thPage"), {"alert":'sucess leaving message,Thank you very much.'})
        return render(request, "zh_tw/maininfo.html",{'form': form,'anchor':'#5thPage'})
```

urls.py

`urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^maininfo/$', views.maininfo, name='maininfo'),)`

template: zh_tw/contact.html
(this is an anchor page included by zh_tw/maininfo.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
   {% if alert %}
      alert('{{alert}}');
   {% endif %}
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument for reverse is the name or the view module in the urlpattern. In your case, it should be

```
views.maininfo
```

or

```
'maininfo'
```

Moreover, $ indicates the end of a string in Python regular expression. Thus you may not be able to resolve the  '/maininfo/#5thPage' using the pattern ^maininfo/$. Find more info here :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/ .